# Losing \n when sent to other form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project where im supposed to send a list of titles to a "central computer".
My problem is that when I send them with the button sendAll I lose a couple och linebreaks.
Anyone got some advice on how to get this to work? 
Since this is a school assignment I cant access the "central computer". I can only work with my own program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Avdelningsrapport
{
    public partial class KlientForm : Form
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        int port = 12345;
        FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader();
        List<Book> ListOfBooks = FileLoader.BookIndex;

        public KlientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            client.NoDelay = true;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }       
        private void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Book item in ListOfBooks)
            {
                listBoxObj.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!client.Connected) StartConnection();
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                btnConnect.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
        public async void StartConnection()
        {
            try 
            {
                IPAddress adress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                await client.ConnectAsync(adress, port);
            }
            catch (Exception error) { MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text); return;}
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
            btnSendAll.Enabled = true;
            btnSendMarked.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void btnSendAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!client.Connected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Du måste ansluta till servern.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (listBoxObj.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Det finns inga böcker att skicka.");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Book item in listBoxObj.Items)
                    {
                        StartSend(item.ToString());
                    }
                    ListOfBooks.Clear();
                    listBoxObj.Items.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        private void btnSendMarked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!client.Connected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Du måste ansluta till servern.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (listBoxObj.SelectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Du måste välja en bok du vill skicka.");
                }
                else
                {
                    StartSend(listBoxObj.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    ListOfBooks.RemoveAt(listBoxObj.SelectedIndex);
                    listBoxObj.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxObj.SelectedIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        public async void StartSend(string SendingBook)
        {
            byte[] outData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(SendingBook);
            try
            {
                await client.GetStream().WriteAsync(outData, 0, outData.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception error) { MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text); return; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not adding a return.  Try this :             byte[] outData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(SendingBook + "\n");

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same result. I've also tried putting a nested for loop in the foreach loop to slow down the transfer speed but that also generated the same result.

Comment: Then you are having issues on the receive end.  Don't forget ReadLine() removes the "\n".

Comment: I pushed up the count on the nested for loop way up instead, that worked for me. Thanks